# Find a redirection on registration

Tags: drupal

In Drupal, there is a site I have to work on that has an annoying quirk.

Anytime someone registers, they are redirected to a custom page. I have grepped for drupal_goto, and looked in the database to find out what is causing this redirect to happen.

Whats the most effective way to track this down???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. A rogue drupal_goto() statement implemented by previous developer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... offers several modifications of the Drupal login system in an external module by offering the following features and usability improvements:
>
> - Allow users to login using either their username OR their e-mail address.
> - Allow users to login immediately.
> - Provide a login form on Access Denied pages for non-logged-in (anonymous) users.
> - The module provides two login block options: One uses JavaScript to display the form within the block immediately upon clicking "log in". The other brings the user to a separate page, but returns the user to their original page upon login.
> - Customize the registration form with two e-mail fields to ensure accuracy.
> - Optionally redirect the user to a specific page when using the 'immediate login' feature.
> - Optionally redirect the user to a specific page upon validation of their e-mail address.
> - Optionally display a user message indicating a successful login.
> - Optionally combine both the login and registration form on one page.
> - Optionally have unvalidated users purged from the system at a pre-defined interval (please read the CAVEATS section of INSTALL.txt for important information on configuring this feature!).
> - Integrates with Rules module to do various tasks when a user validates via email validation process.

Comment: No, I meant the opposite. There was a rogue drupal_goto in code.